# How to find out IP address and default gateway in XP in cmd when DHCP is enabled?

Tags: windows-xp, netsh

When DHCP is disabled and network is setup manually, I can run

```
netsh interface ip show config
```

to see IP address and default gateway. However, when DHCP is enabled I can see only that DHCP is enabled and DNS server address.

Is there a way to see a client IP address and a default gateway in XP via command prompt and `netsh` when DHCP is enabled?

Comment: There's always `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`

Comment: Ok, I don't need to change a configuration, just to read the information. But, only `ipconfig` is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipconfig` is the command that you need for this.